# What is writing/reading to a mounted share in a VirtualBox Linux guest

Tags: linux, windows, virtualbox, disk

I have a Linux guest running on a Windows 10 machine in VirtualBox.

One NTFS-drive of the host has a directory shared with the Linux guest via the "Shared Folders" configuration

Machine Folders ->

- Name: windows-shared
- Path F:\VM-Shared
- Auto-mount: True
- Access: Full

it appears at `/media/sf_windows-shared` and is mounted in the home directory via

`sudo mount -t ntfs -o defaults,bind /media/sf_windows-shared /home/user/windows-shared/`

It has been so for a long time. Months.

Lately, at most since a couple of weeks, this drive F:\ keeps spinning up, without me wanting this. The Windows host does not use it, it is a drive for backups of the Linux guest, which run automated 4 times a day. I've set the "HDD sleep time" to 4 minutes in the Windows power configuration, so that it goes to sleep after the backup has been made (this drops the power consumption by ~10W in a 24/7 system).

I've used `Process Manager` (`procmon`) on the Windows host to see what is causing the writes to the disk, and thus causing it to spin up, and I only get entries from `VBoxHeadless.exe`, which indicates that it is VirtualBox which is causing the drive to spin up.

There is something accessing the disk every 10 seconds. In `procmon` I can see that it is the folder `F:\VM-Shared` which is getting accessed. But it is not really this what makes the drive wake up, since it manages to go to sleep for a couple of minutes before if wakes up again (after about 10-20 minutes)

These are two samples of the data shown in procmon

```
13:17:51,0605497    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_CREATE   F:\VM-Shared    Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: , Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened  [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220
13:17:51,0606371    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_QUERY_VOLUME_INFORMATION F:\VM-Shared    Type: QuerySizeInformationVolume, TotalAllocationUnits: 2.441.575.935, AvailableAllocationUnits: 1.182.175.799, SectorsPerAllocationUnit: 8, BytesPerSector: 512    [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220
13:17:51,0606763    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_CLEANUP  F:\VM-Shared        [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220
13:17:51,0607213    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_CLOSE    F:\VM-Shared        [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220
13:17:51,0608466    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_CREATE   F:\VM-Shared    Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: , Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened  [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220
13:17:51,0608944    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_QUERY_VOLUME_INFORMATION F:\VM-Shared    Type: QueryInformationVolume, VolumeCreationTime: 25.04.2018 21:23:10, VolumeSerialNumber: DADA-A185, SupportsObjects: True, VolumeLabel: 10TB  [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220
13:17:51,0609202    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_CLEANUP  F:\VM-Shared        [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220
13:17:51,0609430    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_CLOSE    F:\VM-Shared        [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220
13:17:51,0610390    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_CREATE   F:\VM-Shared    Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: , Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened  [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220
13:17:51,0610790    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_QUERY_VOLUME_INFORMATION F:\VM-Shared    Type: QueryAttributeInformationVolume, FileSystemAttributes: Case Preserved, Case Sensitive, Unicode, ACLs, Compression, Named Streams, EFS, Object IDs, Reparse Points, Sparse Files, Quotas, Transactions, 0x3c00600, MaximumComponentNameLength: 255, FileSystemName: NTFS   [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220
13:17:51,0611011    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_CLEANUP  F:\VM-Shared        [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220
13:17:51,0611227    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_CLOSE    F:\VM-Shared        [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220
13:17:51,0635221    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_CREATE   F:\VM-Shared    Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: , Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened  [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220
13:17:51,0635747    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_QUERY_VOLUME_INFORMATION F:\VM-Shared    Type: QuerySizeInformationVolume, TotalAllocationUnits: 2.441.575.935, AvailableAllocationUnits: 1.182.175.799, SectorsPerAllocationUnit: 8, BytesPerSector: 512    [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220
13:17:51,0635976    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_CLEANUP  F:\VM-Shared        [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220
13:17:51,0636225    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_CLOSE    F:\VM-Shared        [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220
13:17:51,0637197    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_CREATE   F:\VM-Shared    Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: , Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened  [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220
13:17:51,0637601    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_QUERY_VOLUME_INFORMATION F:\VM-Shared    Type: QueryInformationVolume, VolumeCreationTime: 25.04.2018 21:23:10, VolumeSerialNumber: DADA-A185, SupportsObjects: True, VolumeLabel: 10TB  [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220
13:17:51,0637842    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_CLEANUP  F:\VM-Shared        [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220
13:17:51,0638063    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_CLOSE    F:\VM-Shared        [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220
13:17:51,0638949    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_CREATE   F:\VM-Shared    Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: , Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened  [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220
13:17:51,0639321    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_QUERY_VOLUME_INFORMATION F:\VM-Shared    Type: QueryAttributeInformationVolume, FileSystemAttributes: Case Preserved, Case Sensitive, Unicode, ACLs, Compression, Named Streams, EFS, Object IDs, Reparse Points, Sparse Files, Quotas, Transactions, 0x3c00600, MaximumComponentNameLength: 255, FileSystemName: NTFS   [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220
13:17:51,0639537    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_CLEANUP  F:\VM-Shared        [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220
13:17:51,0639750    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_CLOSE    F:\VM-Shared        [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220
13:17:51,0645157    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_CREATE   F:\VM-Shared    Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: , Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened  [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220
13:17:51,0645761    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_QUERY_VOLUME_INFORMATION F:\VM-Shared    Type: QuerySizeInformationVolume, TotalAllocationUnits: 2.441.575.935, AvailableAllocationUnits: 1.182.175.799, SectorsPerAllocationUnit: 8, BytesPerSector: 512    [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220
13:17:51,0646006    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_CLEANUP  F:\VM-Shared        [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220
13:17:51,0646260    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_CLOSE    F:\VM-Shared        [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220
13:17:51,0647276    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_CREATE   F:\VM-Shared    Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: , Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened  [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220
13:17:51,0647758    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_QUERY_VOLUME_INFORMATION F:\VM-Shared    Type: QueryInformationVolume, VolumeCreationTime: 25.04.2018 21:23:10, VolumeSerialNumber: DADA-A185, SupportsObjects: True, VolumeLabel: 10TB  [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220
13:17:51,0648003    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_CLEANUP  F:\VM-Shared        [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220
13:17:51,0648265    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_CLOSE    F:\VM-Shared        [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220
13:17:51,0649384    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_CREATE   F:\VM-Shared    Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: , Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened  [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220
13:17:51,0649931    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_QUERY_VOLUME_INFORMATION F:\VM-Shared    Type: QueryAttributeInformationVolume, FileSystemAttributes: Case Preserved, Case Sensitive, Unicode, ACLs, Compression, Named Streams, EFS, Object IDs, Reparse Points, Sparse Files, Quotas, Transactions, 0x3c00600, MaximumComponentNameLength: 255, FileSystemName: NTFS   [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220
13:17:51,0650262    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_CLEANUP  F:\VM-Shared        [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220
13:17:51,0650580    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_CLOSE    F:\VM-Shared        [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220

13:18:01,0623528    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_CREATE   F:\VM-Shared    Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: , Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened  [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220
13:18:01,0624198    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_QUERY_VOLUME_INFORMATION F:\VM-Shared    Type: QuerySizeInformationVolume, TotalAllocationUnits: 2.441.575.935, AvailableAllocationUnits: 1.182.175.799, SectorsPerAllocationUnit: 8, BytesPerSector: 512    [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220
13:18:01,0624459    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_CLEANUP  F:\VM-Shared        [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220
13:18:01,0624745    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_CLOSE    F:\VM-Shared        [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220
13:18:01,0625897    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_CREATE   F:\VM-Shared    Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: , Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened  [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220
13:18:01,0626358    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_QUERY_VOLUME_INFORMATION F:\VM-Shared    Type: QueryInformationVolume, VolumeCreationTime: 25.04.2018 21:23:10, VolumeSerialNumber: DADA-A185, SupportsObjects: True, VolumeLabel: 10TB  [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220
13:18:01,0626612    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_CLEANUP  F:\VM-Shared        [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220
13:18:01,0626852    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_CLOSE    F:\VM-Shared        [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220
13:18:01,0627873    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_CREATE   F:\VM-Shared    Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: , Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened  [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220
13:18:01,0628294    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_QUERY_VOLUME_INFORMATION F:\VM-Shared    Type: QueryAttributeInformationVolume, FileSystemAttributes: Case Preserved, Case Sensitive, Unicode, ACLs, Compression, Named Streams, EFS, Object IDs, Reparse Points, Sparse Files, Quotas, Transactions, 0x3c00600, MaximumComponentNameLength: 255, FileSystemName: NTFS   [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220
13:18:01,0628527    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_CLEANUP  F:\VM-Shared        [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220
13:18:01,0628756    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_CLOSE    F:\VM-Shared        [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220
13:18:01,0645594    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_CREATE   F:\VM-Shared    Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: , Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened  [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220
13:18:01,0646247    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_QUERY_VOLUME_INFORMATION F:\VM-Shared    Type: QuerySizeInformationVolume, TotalAllocationUnits: 2.441.575.935, AvailableAllocationUnits: 1.182.175.799, SectorsPerAllocationUnit: 8, BytesPerSector: 512    [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220
13:18:01,0646570    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_CLEANUP  F:\VM-Shared        [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220
13:18:01,0646970    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_CLOSE    F:\VM-Shared        [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220
13:18:01,0648440    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_CREATE   F:\VM-Shared    Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: , Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened  [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220
13:18:01,0649057    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_QUERY_VOLUME_INFORMATION F:\VM-Shared    Type: QueryInformationVolume, VolumeCreationTime: 25.04.2018 21:23:10, VolumeSerialNumber: DADA-A185, SupportsObjects: True, VolumeLabel: 10TB  [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220
13:18:01,0649404    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_CLEANUP  F:\VM-Shared        [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220
13:18:01,0649768    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_CLOSE    F:\VM-Shared        [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220
13:18:01,0651242    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_CREATE   F:\VM-Shared    Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: , Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened  [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220
13:18:01,0651867    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_QUERY_VOLUME_INFORMATION F:\VM-Shared    Type: QueryAttributeInformationVolume, FileSystemAttributes: Case Preserved, Case Sensitive, Unicode, ACLs, Compression, Named Streams, EFS, Object IDs, Reparse Points, Sparse Files, Quotas, Transactions, 0x3c00600, MaximumComponentNameLength: 255, FileSystemName: NTFS   [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220
13:18:01,0652226    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_CLEANUP  F:\VM-Shared        [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220
13:18:01,0652577    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_CLOSE    F:\VM-Shared        [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220
13:18:01,0665132    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_CREATE   F:\VM-Shared    Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: , Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened  [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220
13:18:01,0665593    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_QUERY_VOLUME_INFORMATION F:\VM-Shared    Type: QuerySizeInformationVolume, TotalAllocationUnits: 2.441.575.935, AvailableAllocationUnits: 1.182.175.799, SectorsPerAllocationUnit: 8, BytesPerSector: 512    [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220
13:18:01,0665801    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_CLEANUP  F:\VM-Shared        [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220
13:18:01,0666038    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_CLOSE    F:\VM-Shared        [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220
13:18:01,0667027    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_CREATE   F:\VM-Shared    Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: , Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened  [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220
13:18:01,0667439    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_QUERY_VOLUME_INFORMATION F:\VM-Shared    Type: QueryInformationVolume, VolumeCreationTime: 25.04.2018 21:23:10, VolumeSerialNumber: DADA-A185, SupportsObjects: True, VolumeLabel: 10TB  [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220
13:18:01,0667692    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_CLEANUP  F:\VM-Shared        [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220
13:18:01,0667925    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_CLOSE    F:\VM-Shared        [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220
13:18:01,0669081    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_CREATE   F:\VM-Shared    Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: , Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened  [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220
13:18:01,0671025    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_QUERY_VOLUME_INFORMATION F:\VM-Shared    Type: QueryAttributeInformationVolume, FileSystemAttributes: Case Preserved, Case Sensitive, Unicode, ACLs, Compression, Named Streams, EFS, Object IDs, Reparse Points, Sparse Files, Quotas, Transactions, 0x3c00600, MaximumComponentNameLength: 255, FileSystemName: NTFS   [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220
13:18:01,0671376    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_CLEANUP  F:\VM-Shared        [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220
13:18:01,0671735    VBoxHeadless.exe    8280    IRP_MJ_CLOSE    F:\VM-Shared        [redacted] --comment "Ubuntu Server" --startvm [redacted] --vrde config "--sup-hardening-log=[redacted]\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Server\Logs\VBoxHardening.log"    8544    8220
```

I need to find out what is causing this disc access from within the VM. I've tried `inotifywait -e access /home/user/windows-shared/`, but that does not show anything. I would probably need to use the `-r` (recursive) flag, but the directory contains many thousands of files. I've tried it once but it wouldn't finish setting up the command.

I'm trying to use `dstat` and `iotop`, but somehow I can't get it to look at exactly that mount.

This is a HGST Ultrastar HUH721010ALE600/0F27604, the cost of having it running 24/7 would be a neglectable 25€/year. But there are also other drives which do sleep properly. Would it be the best to touch & sync every minute to keep the that drive awake?

What can I do to find the root cause?